# joining two tables which just have just single columns and doing row-wise addition of columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables physics and Chemistry. They both have single columns. I need to join the two tables on these columns and do a row-wise addition.

```
Physics      
34                
45                
67                
23
```

```
Chemistry 
55
89
45
35
```

I need to join these two tables and do row wise addition to produce a column as

```
Total_score
89
134
112
58
```

I need to order the results in descending order of `total_score` and if two score are similar for two cases, priority should be given to physics score.

Comment: How do you know 34 needs to be added to 55? Rows in a relational database have no sort order, so there is no such thing as the "first row" or "second row".

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Why did you remove the edit from @a_horse_with_no_name? He made the post more readable but you made it worse again. Btw. "I need..." is not a question....

Comment: Chiming in with @a_horse_with_no_name. In my opinion, you have an implicit idea of a row number in both your tables. I think what you *should* do is add a row_number (or ID) column to both your tables, and join rows on that column.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Need to list all possible total score a student can get which I interpreted as row wise sum of two columns.

Comment: Thanks @Hellmar Becker. I tried adding a row  number to both the columns but I am still not getting the result. I need to list all possible total score a student can get.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.score AS 'Physics',t2.score AS 'Chemistry',(t1.score+t2.score) AS Total_Score
FROM table1 t1,table2 t2
ORDER BY Total_Score,Physics desc
```